How do I translate partially translated texts on my Wordpress website
I am new to wordpress and I am encountering a problem with translation from English to Danish. My theme and plugins are in Danish, but on my post page, where it is possible to navigate to my posts, it still says in English ‘Read more’?

When I look in the code, I see that I have a plugin called Spicebox, but I don't see how it gets the text value?

I've tried using Loco Translate and tried searching for Read more, but it doesn't find anything?
Does anyone know how I can get it translated?
UPDATE:
I found out after some investigation of the PHP files in the file manager that Read more is a hard coded value which is located in a helper function for my parent theme Spice software.
helper-function.php in Spice-Software


Check that the theme or plugin has localized the "Read More" text - it may have been overlooked by translators.
Themes and plugins should have a folder called "languages" that contain the language files used in localization.
For plugins this should be <root>\wp-content\plugins\<pluginname>
For themes: <root>\wp-content\themes\<themename>
Using Spicepress as our example, the language folder would be
public_html\wp-content\themes\spicepress\languages on my website.
In this folder is a Portable Object Template file (pot).

The file contains all the text referenced by the theme, including where in code that reference is made.
"Read More" text is defined in the pot file:
#: content-page.php:24 content-single.php:34 content.php:41 
#: content.php:45  
#: content.php:53 functions/template-tags.php:53  
#: functions/template-tags.php:263 index-news.php:60  
#: template/template-page-full-width.php:29  
msgid "Read More"
msgstr ""

Placing the translated text "Læs mere" (I used Google Translate) between the empty quotation marks after msgstr and compiling to .mo / .po will generate the needed language files. WordPress localization documentation has instructions for compiling.
The compiled files will only have the text which has been translated, so the files sizes will be smaller than the main .pot file
A simple way to do this is use Poedit. The application provides an interface for handling the translations and will generate the po/mo files.
Load the spicepress.pot file in Poedit, make your change and save.
Rename the .mo file using the format of _.mo
For my testing I did da_DK.mo, for Danish Denmark. Once I renamed and uploaded to the Spicepress theme language folder the translation took effect. I did not upload the .po file.
I also set the language to "Dansk" in WordPress Settings -> General
Additional Info:

Installing WordPress in your language
ISO-639 Language Codes
ISO-3166 Country Codes


I have added “læs mere” to mgstr in the language file PO. Must the file then be complied? Because I cannot see any changes.

I got it to work, I'll update my answer

Sorry for taking so long to reply. I have tried your approach but it didn't work. I found out after some investigation of the PHP files in the file manager that Read more is a hard coded value which is located in a helper function for my parent theme Spice software. The best solution is your method with translation strings.

See my update :-)

@Godfather75 Glad you found a work around.
The first string to that function "get_theme_mod" is the msgid for the desired text translation. The second string is the default value returned if the msgid can't be found.
To add confusion to the mix, I uploaded the Spice Software theme just now, and I get "Cras Vitae" instead of Read More, with no additional translating on my end.
